# Load static angular2 web project using vert.x

Tags: angular, vert.x

We can load static web pages using vert.x by putting index.html in an assets folder and giving its path in Router

```
router.route("/assets/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("assets"));
```

If I put an Angular2 build project inside assets folder and try to load index.html, browser fails to understand Angular2 as no dependencies are loaded in browser.

As I know we can use lite-server or node to run Angular2 project.

Is there any way to use vert.x to load Angular2 project or is there any other solution possible without web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in *Vert.x* docs,

> Any requests to paths handled by the static handler will result in
>   files being served from a directory on the file system or from the
>   classpath. The default static file directory is webroot but this can
>   be configured.

As you have configured the default web root folder to be ***assets*** any request to path ***/assets/*** will result to file under ***assets/assets/*** to be served as stated also by the official documentation:

> For example, if there was a request with path /static/css/mystyles.css
>   the static serve will look for a file in the directory
>   webroot/static/css/mystyle.css.

E.g. a request with a path */assets/js/angular2.js* will instruct the server to look for a file under *assets/assets/js/angular2.js* thus you should:

- Either move your static assets under *assets/assets/* folder.
- Or keep the default root folder and place your static files under *webroot/assets*.

Answer (score 2):

Add-on: for any one  who stumbles to this post.
Below snippet to handle refresh on browser.

Stack - Vertx serving angular 2 files.

```
   // Create a router endpoint for the static content.

   basically route any files - js, css, jpg etc
   router.route("/*")
   .handler(StaticHandler.create("webroot").setCachingEnabled(false));

   // so anything else re route to home page
   router.route("/*").handler(rc -> {
        logger.info("For refresh handling");

        rc.response().sendFile("webroot/index.html");

   });
```